# How to make a Google+ circle a strict subset of another circle?

Tags: google-plus, privacy

I would like to create two circles. One called `children` and one called `family`. Naturally all members of `children` circle are also members of `family` circle but the `family` circle contains more. `children` is a strict subset of `family`.  And I would like that all members of the `children` circle are automatically members of the `family` circle. How can I achieve this?

Furthermore I would like to expand this. Next I would like to create another circle called `photo friends`, which automatically should contain all members of the `familiy` circle. And after this I would like to create `friends` which contain all members of `photo friends`.

In the end I would like to publish photos: those which are only for my children, those which are for the family, those which are for my photo friends and those which are for all other friends. And I do not want to maintain for every single photo a list of circles. Instead I only want to define one single level of confidentiality for each photo. Is this possible with Google+?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's currently not possible in `Google+` to denote a Circle as a subset of another. The setup you want to do would take the setup time down on creating multiple circles with duplicate people in order to only have to select 1 circle when sharing something, but they don't have that yet.

Comment: Strange. I think this is a very basic feature for a system implementing [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control). And I think the circles should be such a system. Everything else does not make much sense to me.

Comment: ahh, but they did implement a mandator access control system in the very basic sense of it. Getting more complicated than putting people in different circles *could* have made Google+ *sound* more complicated then it needed to be. Plus as you add more complexity the possibility of bugs affecting privacy/security goes up.

Comment: But being able to put a circle in a circle avoids redundant configuration and allows following the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principal. And by this it is in the end less prone to errors.

Comment: yes, there is a subset of us that want things to be uber micro-manageable (i'm not disagreeing with you) but the complexity of those types of systems can be troublesome for functionality and user adoption.